# Calculating the Rabi frequency of a pulse

Tags: quantum-spin, laser-interaction, rabi-model

If I apply a $\frac{π}{2}$ pulse of linewidth 5MHz centred at 99MHz to a nuclear spin also centred at 99MHz, is there a way to calculate a Rabi frequency of this interaction? I realise the Rabi frequency is usually for continuous fields that cause oscillation between the ground and excited state, but is it possible to calculate something similar for a pulse? And how would this change if the frequency of the nucleus was say 98Mhz instead?

Answer (score 1):

This problem can be solved if you extend it to the case of a pulse wave of period $T$ and pulse time $\tau$ and you assume $T\gg\tau$. Then, by Fourier analysis, you will write
$$
f(t) = \frac{\tau}{T} + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{2}{n\pi} \sin\left(\frac{\pi n\tau}{T}\right) \cos\left(\frac{2\pi n}{T} t\right).
$$
Then, the Hamiltonian can be written as
$$
 H = E\sigma_3+gf(t)\sigma_1
$$
being $\sigma_3$ and $\sigma_1$ Pauli matrices (I am assuming spin 1/2) and $g$ the coupling. Therefore, you can proceed in the standard way to get the Rabi frequency by applying the rotating wave approximation to this system. You can observe that there will be a harmonic $n_0$ that will fulfil the resonance equation, $2E=2n_0\pi\hbar/T$, producing the corresponding Rabi frequency $g/n_0\pi$.